# How can I use local Storage with the login functionality in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I am trying to create a login functionality where if the user is logged in he/she should be redirected to /health page but if he/she is not logged in , the user should be automatically redirected to /login page. While doing this I came across the concept of local storage I understood and tried implementing it. However, it is not fetching the desired results.

Comment: it doesn't seem like you are accessing your local storage data, use it like this to check if the user logged in `localStorage.getItem('isLog')==='true'`

Comment: hi @besufkad, thanks for replying. Where should I put this?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell you are missing initializing your `isLog` state from localStorage. After a user authenticates you set the storage and redirect to the "/health" route, but if a user is already logged in and reloads the page, the `App` will reinitialize its `isLog` state back to `false`.

Using a [state lazy initializer function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) you can read the localStorage for the `isLog` key and set the initial state.

```
const [isLog, setState] = useState(() => {
  return !!JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("isLog"));
});
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-use-local-storage-with-the-login-functionality-in-react]

You can also simplify your redirect logic by moving it below all your routes other then the "404" match all routes.

Example:

```
<Switch>
  <Route path="/login">
    <Login isLogIn={handleLogin} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/health" component={Health} />
  <Route path="/useradmin"  component={UserAdmin} />
  <Redirect exact from="/" to={isLog ? "/health" : "/login"} />
  <Route path="*">NOT FOUND</Route>
</Switch>
```